# posenet p5js position stops updating when I move to another tab

Tags: audio, position, p5.js

I'm coding with posenet and p5js. I made a grid on my screen which plays different audio fragments on different x ranges. This works very well. However, if I keep it running and open another tab in my chrome webbrowser, the x position gets stuck in one area (it doesn't update anymore) and the same audio fragment is repeated until you get crazy.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

Comment: It would be worthwhile having a skim over [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again. A minimal example and perhaps a [js] tag will help reach the correct audience. You might also want to say if this problem persists across all browsers or just chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some code would be great to be honest, but variables shouldn't really get stuck if you open another tab and so on, are you sure you haven't just missssspelled some variable, or some function or did one of those random mistakes?

If it truly is the p5.js I guess just try checking everytime draw fires if your canvas is still focused.

I believe you can also have canvas.hasFocus... exept you'd have to declare createCanvas as a variable *(cause canvas is basically just a button or a textArea to html and javascript and p5)*

Also I think there's a command to only allow for one audio channel and stuff in js and p5...

```
    function draw() {
      if(document.hasFocus()){
  // all of your other code even 
  // background() and stuff...
       }
    }
```